# Play framework 2.0.4 web requests time out after 10 seconds

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having an annoying bug while using the Play framework. When I do a web call to a method that takes longer than 10 seconds, I recieve an empty response. For example: The following web call

```
public static Result testException() throws Exception {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(20000);
    throw new Exception("Oops, I've thrown an exception");
}
```

is mapped in my /conf/routes

```
GET     /oops                               controllers.Application.testException()
```

When I go to the page in my web browser or with PostMan, I get a blank page after 10 seconds. However, after 20 seconds, I see the stacktrace of my exception in my log files.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to change the akka configuration in my application.conf, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What HTTP response code does your returned page have? I guess Play's connection timeout is 10 s and it returns an error code with empty page. And your action method actually does answer, but too late and it only leads to a logged message.

Comment: The web call returns an HTTP 200 response. You mentioned that play has a connection timeout. Is there a way to configure this value? Thx for the help

Comment: Unfortunately not. Play uses Netty as an HTTP server. I guess it's in some Netty config.